# Unable to do a 'get' using Eclipse TEE Plugin (TFS)

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I am running into an issue where the Eclipse TEE/TFS plugin is not allowing me to download the latest scripts out of TFS. When I right click in Project Explorer & select Team, none of the features are available (Get latest version, Rollback, etc). Only Apply Patch and Share Project appear under 'Team' sub menu item. I am connected to the TFS project under Team Explorer and my Local Path is appearing properly. Workspace and project appears to be setup properly - I setup the same way on another machine, yet I'm running into this issue.[image]

Comment: Are you able to check in Pending Changes in Team Explorer? If you select one file or folder under  `Test Automation` folder, are you able to see the TFS features? If you browse to a file in Source Control Explorer, are you able to see `Get latest version` option?

Comment: Since this is a test machine, I won't be doing any edits on the scripts (so there won't be any Pending Changes). Anything worked out of the Project Explorer (right click >> Team) shows up just as the graphic does below. If I go to the TFVC Source Control tab, I can right click on folders and files and see all the TFS menu items. This is a good work around for right now.

Comment: How about creating a new eclipse workspace and import the project from TFS? Are you able to see the TFS features?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is browsing to the files in Source Control Explorer.

Also. try to create a new eclipse workspace and import the project from TFS to see whether your issue can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The root "RF Scripting" folder you opened in the Project Explorer is not a workspace, so the plugin does not consider it and all its sub folders as TFS working folder.

If you want to get the TFS options from Project Explorer, click "File -> Open Projects from File System... -> Directory..." and then choose "C:\RFTestAutoDev\RF Scripting\xxxTest Automation (I suspect this is the folder you configured as workspace)" as the directory.